# How can I remove digits after a tab?

Tags: unix, sed

I have two columns in my file. 
Example: The first column has movie titles and the second column has its ratings.

```
Planet51     48
Avengers     97
Aladdin      61
```

I want to remove the ratings from the file and just have the column containing movie titles using sed command. I am using the command `$sed 's/[0-9]//g' input > output`.

However, this removes all digits in the file, so my output is

```
Planet     
Avengers     
Aladdin
```

instead of

```
Planet51     
Avengers     
Aladdin
```

How can I fix my sed command so that it will only remove digits after the tab space? I tried messing around with some metacharacters (specifically \t)but I just confused myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do

```
sed 's/\t[0-9]*//' input > output
```

or indeed just

```
sed 's/\t.*//' input > output
```

to delete *everything* after the tab.

(Tested with GNU sed; the `\t` doesn't seem to be guaranteed by POSIX. In a script it might be more portable to let the command contain a literal tab character instead of `\t`).

Answer (score 2):

If you have the GNU coreutils installed:

```
$ cut -f1 file.txt
Planet51
Avengers
Aladdin
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just print first column.

```
awk '{print $1}' file
Planet51
Avengers
Aladdin
```